# iOs. Screen flash on input tap

Tags: html, ios, wordpress

I have a wordpress contact form (made with wpcf7).

Each time a user moves from form field to form field on the contact form the screen seems to flash/scroll up to the top of the form and then centres back on the active field.

Here is typical html of form inputs:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="wpcf7-form" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>First name</label>
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first_name">
                <input type="text" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40" value="" name="first_name">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap last_name">
                <input type="text" aria-invalid="false" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control" name="last_name">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Reproduced only on iPhones (iOs 8, 9.3) in Safari and Chrome.
Аnyone experienced this?

Comment: What WordPress theme are you using? It almost sounds like it could be trying to make changes when a resize is detected, and opening the keyboard when focussing form inputs can trigger a resize event.

Comment: We use customized standard theme.

Comment: If you change themes does the problem go away?